# Model selection in R, do I include interactions between variables?

Tags: r

So I have looked around, and I can't seem to work this out from what I've found.

I'm trying to calculate BIC for three models I have,

```
resistivity1 = rho_i*(1 + (3/8)*lam*(1/thickness))

resistivity2 = rho_i(1 + (3/2)*lam*(1/grains)*(R/(1-R)))

resistivity3 = rho_i*(1 + (3/8)*lam*(1/thickness) + (3/2)*lam*(1/grains)*(R/(1-R)))
```

R, lam, and rho_i are some constants which for now I have missed out- I have particular values for these.

This is what I've written in R,

```
BIC(lm(formula = resistivity ~ 1 + (3/8)*I(1/thickness), data=z))

BIC(lm(formula = resistivity ~ 1 + (3/2)*I(1/grains), data=z)) 

BIC(lm(formula = resistivity ~ I(1 + (3/8)*I(1/thickness) + (3/2)*I(1/grains)), data=z))
```

If anyone needs to know, this is what the head of my data looks like,

```
|   | thickness | grains | resistivity |
---------------------------------------|
| 1 |     524.4 |   1829 |        15.6 | 
| 2 |     670.5 |   3155 |    450000.0 |
| 3 |     943.4 |   3859 |        22.1 |
| 4 |    1072.3 |   4585 |        10.9 |
```

Basically, I don't know if what I've written in R is the same as the models defined above. Is it necessary to include the interactions `resistivity:thickness`, `resistivity:grains` as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `?formula` goes over all of this.

Comment: @Chrisss Yes, I've seen this. I guess what  I need to know is whether the interaction terms are appropriate in this case. I can't think of a time when they would be used?

Comment: This appears much more appropriate for CrossValidated.com. The questions about what to do critically depends on sample size and the underlying scientific situation, neither of which is yet available.

Comment: What is the exact question here?

Comment: Sentences in your question like *"What do `~` and `I()` do?"* seem to contradict your comment that *"Yes, I've seen this [`?formula`]. I guess what I need to know is whether the interaction terms are appropriate in this case"*

Comment: @42- if this is a statistical question, use of `anova` could help. But the question of this post is not really made clear. Is it about `formula`, or is it about interaction terms in models? ...

Comment: Is your question "How do I calculate BIC for specific coefficients?" Using `lm`, you are estimating new parameters, creating a new model, and calculating BIC based on that. It seems like you have coefficients in mind, e.g., `rho_i`, and `rho_i * 3/8` and you want to know the BIC for a model with those coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an `anova` on both models, one with, and one without interaction. It should show you if adding the interaction better explains your data. In case not, leave it out.

Since you did not include a reproducible example, take this as an guide:

```
anova(lm(y~a+b), lm(y~a+b+a:b))
```

Tells you if adding interaction `a:b` improves the model.

On a dataset (model without sense):

```
data(french_fries)
attach(french_fries)
anova(lm(potato ~ time + treatment), # model 1 with no interaction
      lm(potato ~ time * treatment)) # model 2 with interaction
```

The output tells that using the interaction improves the model (lower `RSS`), but not significantly:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: potato ~ time + treatment
Model 2: potato ~ time * treatment
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1    683 8128.6                           
2    665 8012.6 18    115.93 0.5345 0.9422
```